# React-Select & React-Flow overlapping

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm using React-Select and React-Flow (https://reactflow.dev/) for a project.
Now unfortunately, the two are overlapping, making my react-select dropdown unusable.
I didn't edit the css, so I think code does not help, regardless, it is easily reproduced with the following code. Also attached a picture for the effect.

Is there any way I can force the React-Select div on on top? I tried using the z-index, but that doesn't seem to yield the right results.

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactFlow from 'react-flow-renderer';
import Select from 'react-select';

export default const Bug = () => {
    return(
        <div>
            <Select options={[{value:1, label:'option A'}, {value:2, label:'option B'}]}/>
            <ReactFlow/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

[image: React-Select & React Flow bug]

Comment: Where have you tried using the `z-index`?

Comment: Yes, I tried with z-index 1 and 2 on the different classes.

Comment: It is hard to tell from the little code you shared, but you may try to add a `z-index` to the `div` containing the select (also make sure that the element to which you apply the `z-index` has it's `position` declared as `z-index` only works on an element with an explicit `position declaration)

Comment: Sorry for the little code, all css is inherited from the modules, to add it all seemed a bit much. Anyways, adding the `z-index` to the div containg the select worked! Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Shmili Breuer!

Manually adding a `z-index` to the div containing the react-select, which is higher than the `z-index` from React Flow solved my problem!

```js
<Card>
    <Card.Header className='z10'/>
        <Select .../>
    </Card.Header>
    <Card.Body>
        <ReactFlow/>
    </Card.Body>
</Card>
```

```css
.z10 {
    z-index: 10;
}
```